# How do Identified animation is flash animation or flex animation?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flex3, flash

**In this Developing site URL  ( http://slide.zhoyosoft.com ) one intro animation is there .

How do Identified that intro animation is  flash animation or flex animation ?**

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jamesward.com/is_it_flex/

http://www.jamesward.com/is_it_flex/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fslide.zhoyosoft.com%2Fimage.swf

Your answer:
http://slide.zhoyosoft.com/image.swf was NOT built with Flex

I follow a 3 step guide when determining if something was built with Flex.

1. Does it make sense to build it in Flex?
   Flex has great support for interacting with web services, charting, and is typically used for dynamic widgets. If the application does not have any of these qualities it's probably not flex.
2. Does it look like flex? Flex comes with pre-built components that have a unique default style. Most developers don't bother changing the style much. For an example of flex style take a look at http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/inproduct/sdk/flexstore/flexstore.html
3. If still unsure, use the link above.

Comment: thank you so much George Deglin .. I Like your answer .

Your answer very clearly. every body like that .

Comment: Super . i check that your site . woow . it's working . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flex is just a framework on top of Flash, the output is still a Flash file that plays in the Flash Player. I don't think you can differentiate between Flash and Flex in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One of the method flex predefine preloader besed to Identified that

Comment: any functions that Flex has predefined might be legitimately defined in any Flash project too, so that's not exactly foolproof

Answer (score 0):

flex file is much bigger than flah file duw to framework generally 250 kb bigger .and also flex default preloader can tell u its flex .